# One way encryption, saving the hashed string to a file?

Tags: java, encryption, hash

```
public static byte[] createHash( String stringToHash ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    MessageDigest digestor;

    byte[] byteInput = null;

    try {
        digestor = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        digestor.reset();
        byteInput = digestor.digest( stringToHash.getBytes("UTF-8") );
    } catch( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ){};

    return byteInput;

}
```

So I'm trying to make a very very simple method which one way encrypts a string and I am a total encryption noob despite my efforts to understand it by reading online.

The thing is I wanna store this information in a file/dbase (which is really irrelevant as I am not asking how to get or insert info into a dbase). Say I was storing it very simply without any salt in a text file, how would I write the byte array into the text file? Using a single for loop that throws all the bytes into the file or? Because when I try using my class I get the same array of bytes no matter what string I use? Again pardon my complete ignorance, but how do I go about formatting the byte array into the hashed string so I can do a simple encryption of the users password doing login and compare the two strings to each other?

Help is much appreciated and please if you have arrogant comments and the likes, simply refrain from answering my post completely!

Thanks!

Comment: I find it strange that someone replied correctly to it if it really is as vague, incomplete, overly broad and rhetorical??? What is rhetorical about it? Anyways nevermind I found the help I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store a byte array as a string, then encode it using [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html); when you read in the string later on, then decode it back to a byte array.  (This is also useful if e.g. you want to transmit a byte array in a URL; note that the resulting string will be about 33% larger than the original byte array)

If you just want to write a byte array to a file, then use [FileOutputStream#write(byte[] b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d%29)

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting minuses maybe ppl are pissed they can't answer the question like you? Anyways I'm trying to use the Base64 class as you suggested but I'm not sure how exactly I should import it, eclipse doesn't seem to wanna recognize it for me? Again pardon my ignorance but I'm only trying to understand the how and why here.

Comment: You need to download the [Apache codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) jar and import it into your Eclipse project. The jar is available on subversion; you'll need a subversion client to get it, I recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

Comment: Ok now they got really angry, but thanks for the info it was just what I was looking for.